# How do I know what is my floodlight controller's IP address?

Tags: mininet, sdn

Now I am running my virtual machines with floodlight and mininet in the same desktop. Follow the tutorial on the floodlight's website, it indicates that we can use the command to connect mininet to controller. However, I cannot connect the controller successfully. So I am wondering if there is anything wrong for the controller's ip address(I used my virtual machine's ip address in the command). So far I think this is not the controller's ip address. Thank you.

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=<controller ip>,port=6653 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're running Mininet in your VM, try to setup the VM as bridge, then your VM will get an IP and you can set mininet command like this (i.e your controller IP: 10.0.1.5):

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=10.0.1.5,port=6653 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```